# When moving variable declarations to near first-use does it matter if they are after a return statement?

Tags: c++

In other words: in terms of run-time performance via memory and/or speed (comprehension and readability are a given) are these two code blocks equivalent or different?

A, Declare near first-use:

```
double A = /*...*/
double B = /*...*/

if(A > B) return false;

double C = /*...*/
double D = /*...*/

if(C < D) return false;

double E = /*...*/
double F = /*...*/

if(E > F) return false;

double G = /*...*/
double H = /*...*/

if(G < H) return false;

return true;
```

B, Declare all variables first:

```
double A = /*...*/
double B = /*...*/
double C = /*...*/
double D = /*...*/
double E = /*...*/
double F = /*...*/
double G = /*...*/
double H = /*...*/

if(A > B) return false;
if(C < D) return false;
if(E > F) return false;
if(G < H) return false;
return true;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both codes should result in identical object code for modern compilers. These cases are easily recognized and optimized based on basic static analyses, specifically [use-def analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use-define_chain) and [liveness analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liveness_analysis).

Assuming none of the assignments involve earlier variables, the stack frame will only contain 2 doubles for this particular situation since only 2 doubles are live at any point.

When pointers come into play, things may change drastically because of potential aliasing. `volatile`s can also ruin optimization if used inappropriately.

Comment: What if the assignments DO involve earlier variables, or worse, function calls?

Comment: Function calls don't matter: they are delayed until necessary (e.g. to the point at which the variable is used). When earlier variables get used to assign new ones (directly or through a function call), their live ranges extend. This may matter and *could* lead to larger stack frames, though I am fairly certain this is no challenge for modern compilers.

Comment: @MarcClaesen: Function calls can only be delayed if the definition is visible. Otherwise, they may have side effects. Moving a function call with side effect past a possible return statement would alter the observable behavior.

Answer (score 2):

No -- at least with any compiler of which I'm aware, these would produce equivalent (typically identical) object code, and I have a difficult time conceiving of a compiler which would produce significantly different object code for one vs. the other.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter however, I would always declare my variables first because it's a lot more readable that way.

Once you start mixing in declarations all around the place and have them indented then they can be hidden or if at a later date you want to change your code and it needs to be accessed out of scope you'll have to move it anyway ( which may or may not be troublesome )